# Error in if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am writing a little text adventure but I am encountering an error at the beginning.
I want to ask the gender of the player, and everything works well, but the message if a wrong gender is written is not getting displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
        if (scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Frau")) {
            System.out.println("Oh eine Dame des" + sClanname + " Clans");
            sGender = scan.next();
        } else if (scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Mann")) {
            System.out.println("Oh ein Herr des" + sClanname + " Clans");
            sGender = scan.next();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Entschuldige, wir sind hier sehr konservativ...Es gibt nur \"Mann\" oder \"Frau\"");
        }
```

I've also tried

```
    if (scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Frau") || scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Mann")) {
        System.out.println("Oh eine Dame des" + sClanname + " Clans");
        sGender = scan.next();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Entschuldige, wir sind hier sehr konservativ...Es gibt nur \"Mann\" oder \"Frau\"");
    }
```

and

```
if (!scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Frau") && !scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Mann")) {
    System.out.println("Entschuldige, wir sind hier sehr konservativ...Es gibt nur \"Mann\" oder \"Frau\"");
}
```

Comment: You're calling `scan.next()` in every `if` statement, causing it to be executed again if the first condition is `false`. Ask it once and then use that result.

Comment: In the first `else` branch you're going into both `if` and `else` calls to `.next()`, same for the `&&` and `||` conditions below; beyond that it's impossible to say. What error do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not comparing the same `String` in your `if` and `else if` statements, since each call to `scan.next()` returns a new `String` read from the input.

You should store the String in a variable and re-use it:

```
    String s = scan.next();
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Frau")) {
        System.out.println("Oh eine Dame des" + sClanname + " Clans");
        sGender = scan.next();
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Mann")) {
```

Comment: Thank you, i didnt thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

Each scan.next() is trying to scan next line from the input.
If you wana compare the same input save it once in a variable and then use.

Answer (score 0):

Compare sGender instead of scan.next

```
if (scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Frau")) {
            System.out.println("Oh eine Dame des" + sClanname + " Clans");
            sGender = scan.next();
        } else if (sGender.equalsIgnoreCase("Mann")) {
            System.out.println("Oh ein Herr des" + sClanname + " Clans");
            sGender = scan.next();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Entschuldige, wir sind hier sehr konservativ...Es gibt nur \"Mann\" oder \"Frau\"");
        }
```